# Magento 2 error : Command "indexer:reindex" is not defined

Tags: magento2, reindex, indexer

System : Ubuntu 18
Application : Magento2.3
PHP : 7.1

I have two indexer need to be reindex. I have update the indexer on the admin page but it is not work. I also use the following command on the server :

php bin/magento indexer.reindex

but the system reply "Command indexer.reindex" is not defined"

I have gone to the root directory and the cron is working.

I don't know what the problem is ?

Please help......

Answer (score 1):

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

`:` instead of `.`

[Magento DevDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html)

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved. Let me show what the solution :

I tried different function of bin/magento such as "bin/magento setup" or "bin/magento cache" but it will show "There are no commands defined in the XXXXX namespace" I think it is the all function of bin/magento problem not only indexer. So, I run the following command :

$ php bin/magento list

They can not list the function and notice me some error. I think it is the access right problem so I change the owner to all folder again.

$ chown -R XXXX:www-data

Finally, all function of bin/magento are working.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check your permissions
try:
`sudo chown -R XXX:www-data /var/www`
`cd /var/www`
`chmod go-rwx /var/www`
`chgrp -R www-data /var/www`
`chmod -R go-rwx /var/www`
`chmod -R g+rx /var/www`
`chmod -R g+rwx /var/www`
`sudo chown -R XXX:www-data /var/www/<magento folder>/`
`cd <magento folder>/public_html/`
`find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} + && sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} + && sudo chown -R :www-data . && sudo chmod u+x bin/magento`

Remember to Change XXX with your pc name, also
it's: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
`:` instead of `.`

Answer (score 0):

please replace . to : in your command.

Follow this

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Hope it is working fine.